# Passive causative in relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses, causative-verbs

Causative is used to say that you arrange for someone else to do a job for you. For example, "*John has the car repaired*". This is different from "*John has repaired the car*" because the latter sentence means that John did the work himself.

Now, I would like to merge the following two sentences, using a relative clause:
"*John has the car repaired*" - "*Now the car works perfectly*".

I mean something like "*The car, which John has repaired, now works perfectly*". But this sentence is wrong because it means that the car was repaired by John himself. However, I don't know how to get it right. Could you help me out please?

In relation to this question, I began wondering whether there is a way to transform the sentence "*John has the car repaired*" into passive voice. I know that it is already passive in some sense but it still has an object: *the car*. So, is it possible to say something like "*The car was had/got/gotten repaired by John*"?

Comment: John has had the car repaired so that it works perfectly.

Comment: *The car, which John has had repaired, now works perfectly.*

Comment: Don't need the perfect, and it can be a restrictive clause, too: _The car that John had repaired now works perfectly._

Comment: "The car that John had repaired now works perfectly" could be causative or normal past perfect: in the latter sense the sequence of tenses is unusual but possible. "The pie that John had tasted is stale now" isn't causative.

Comment: ... unless John supervises quality control in a pie factory.

Answer (score 1):

As Tinfoil Hat suggested, the following is fine:

> The car, which John has had repaired, now works perfectly.

You could also keep the clauses in the original order:

> John has had the car, which now works perfectly, repaired.

However, "repaired" is now separated from its ancestors by a relatively lengthy clause. Therefore, some people may prefer to postpone ("extrapose") the relative clause:

> John has had the car repaired, which now works perfectly.

As for your last question, either "to be" or "to get" can function as a passive auxiliary:

> The car was repaired by John.
> The car got repaired by John.

(Of course, including "by John" suggests that John repaired it himself.)

Answer (score 0):

> Ever since John had the car repaired, it's been working perfectly.

is an alternative that reverses your original order. The "ever since" somewhat extends/specifies the time period of the original "now". It also emphasizes the fact that John had it repaired rather than it's current working condition. I propose it only because it may flow better than constructions with a relative clause.